# Is Deadpool's mother named Martha?

Tags: marvel, deadpool

I've been reading the recent Deadpool vs Punisher miniseries, and there's this scene that obviously parodies an infamous scene from a certain DC production:

[image]

After this, the Punisher tells Deadpool that his mom's name is Louise. Deadpool's response is "Well, **** you then" before he pulls a gun on him.

The name of Deadpool's mom is never mentioned. Neither is the fact if Deadpool was 'doing a bit' or was serious.

So, is there a canonical mention of Deadpool's mom anywhere? Is her name Martha?

Comment: Just fixed up the tags a little bit to keep them about the question. If you want comic universe questions you should include the [comics] tag.

Comment: @Edlothiad Thanks. Sure thing.

Comment: Ahem; http://marvel.wikia.com/wiki/Hailey_Wilson_(Earth-616)

Comment: @Valorum: Wow. So 'Pool was straight-up lying. Man! Anyway, if you post that as an answer, I'll accept.

Comment: I'm mobile at the moment. Why not post it as a self-answer instead?

Comment: Post when you've time. I can't really take credit. It's your answer :)

Comment: I doubt he'll mind, he's probably repcapped based on upvotes from old answers already

Comment: I've looked at all of the issues referenced in that marvel wikia page - and I can't find any actual mention of her name. I have no idea where they're getting it.

Comment: Why shouldn't we believe the Punisher?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No. Deadpool's mother (according to Marvel's "[Wade Wilson Superstar](https://www.comixology.co.uk/Deadpool-Vol-1-Wade-Wilson-Superstar/digital-comic/518699)" book) is **[Hailey Wilson](http://marvel.wikia.com/wiki/Hailey_Wilson_(Earth-616)).**

> **Deckname [Pseudonym]:** *Deadpool*
>
> **Weitere Decknamen [Other Aliases]:** *Söldner mit der großen Klappe, regenerierender Degenerierter, scharlachroter Komiker, Jack, Chiyonosake (Wolf des
>   Reisweins), Rhodes, Thom Cruz, Peter Parker, Johnny Salvini,
>   Hobgoblin, Denny und zahlreiche andere*
>
> **Angehörige [Relatives]:** *Thomas "Mickey" Wilson (Vater, tot [Father, dead]), **Hailey Wilson (Mutter, tot [Mother, dead])**, Orksa (Exfrau [Ex-wife]), Gretchen Wilson (Exfrau [Ex-wife]), Shiklah
>   (Frau [wife]), Evil Deadpool (Klon [clone]), Widdle Wade (Klon [clone]), Eleanor Camacho
>   (Tochter [daughter]), Carmelita Camacho (Mutter von Ellie, One-Night-Stand, tot [Mother of Ellie, One-Night-Stand, dead])*
>
> **Teamzugehörigkeit: [Team member of]** *Uncanny Avengers, Mercs for Money.
>
>   ehemals [former team member of]: Thunderbolts, X-Force, Deadpool Corps, SHIELD, Frightful Four, Secret
>   Defenders, Waffe X, Heroes for Hire, Agency X, Code Red, Six Pack, One
>   World Church, etc.*

Comment: Yo, why this in German?

Comment: @Möoz - Because it's a German book released in Germany

Comment: @Narusan:   I'd say, at least translate the headings and the relevant part (i.e. all the words that are already **bold**)